# Scheduling using Datetime & Boolean Values

Tags: python, datetime, variables, boolean, schedule

I am working on a project that takes in new data periodically.

1. The initial problem is that function 1 is scheduled to update & aggregate certain variables at a certain time & function 2 is supposed to use the updated variables (but it can’t because variables are local to each function) to make calculations & print at different scheduled time. And I can’t define the the variables in Global because the data will be updated constantly not periodically.
2. So I thought that I could just combine both functions into one function so that the program will see the sets of variable as the same, instead of two different sets of local variables. Then the different “functions” (now processes) would be executed using a `if date.time1 is True:  process1` & `elif date.time2 is True: process2`.

The problem I’m running into here is that it seems that either the simple T/F code that I wrote is incorrect or you can’t use T/F with datetimes. I would really like if someone would please shed some light on my issue(s) and I’m willing to hear a different solution to the first problem or how I can fix the second problem.

Answer (score 0):

I don’t know why I don’t think of these earlier but I simply used the   x = datetime.datetime.now() & y = datetime.date,time,day.(date,time,day) and used if x == y: